# How to encrypt sensive data sent from the server to the mobile application

Tags: encryption, ssl-certificate, rsa

I want to Encrypt the server response (to the mobile app) from being exposed by the attackers (data theft),
I'm already using RSA to encrypt requests sent from the mobile app to the server, public key (on the mobile app) for encryption, and private key (on the server side) for decryption, what I'm worried about is the other direction (from server to mobile), cause If I put a decryption key (private or public) on mobile attacker can get it from there by decompile the app.

- using react-native for mobile
- using Java for server

Comment: At which point are you afraid that the data is stolen? During transfer? From the mobile device?

Comment: I'm afraid to stolen during transfer from server to mobile,  thanks for the reply , from mobile to server I'm not afraid cause even if the attacker gets the public key he won't be able to decrypt the data with it

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? If yes, your content is already encrypted

Comment: yes It's encrypted, but if the attacker stole the key from mobile app, he can decrypt it

Comment: What key? HTTPS negotiates the key on the fly. There is nothing to be stolen.

Comment: I mean the attacker sniffs the keys during the handshake on the fly

Comment: There is no "key sniffing" in ssl handshakes. If that was possible (with a reasonable amount of effort, of course if you have unlimited computation power and time you will be able to break any encryption) SSL would be useless